# Is there a repository of UX Discovery Questions?

Tags: discovery

I was wondering if there is a site or repository of standard UX questions used in the Discovery phase of Website/Portal/Collaboration site.

Comment: Please add some more detail to your question to get good answers. Are these questions you want to ask clients, stakeholders, business owners, users and/or the engineering team? Also please give more detail about the nature and scope of your project.

Comment: Are you asking for heuristic surveys?

Answer (score 2):

I can only assume that you are referring to heuristic evaluation questions. Here is a great guide to conducting an evaluation: http://www.uxforthemasses.com/usability-reviews/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great list of [Heuristic Evaluation Questions](http://www.stcsig.org/usability/topics/articles/he-checklist.html) from the Society for Technical Communication's Usability and User Experience special interest group. They have some questions that help you evaluate discoverability as well as general usability concerns. None are explicit "is this item discoverable?" questions, but they cover the low-level concerns that make up a discoverable interface such as

> Is only (and all) information essential to decision making displayed on the screen?

For more high-level thought about the issue of discoverability consider Scott Berkun's [The Myth of Discoverability](http://www.scottberkun.com/essays/26-the-myth-of-discoverability/) article, which covers why you can't make *everything* equally discoverable and how to decide what should be most discoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the above this is the ultimate [UX repository checklist](https://getenjoyhq.com/research-repository-checklist/)